# In Blogger, is There a Way to Enlarge The Font Size of "X-Large" Tag?

Tags: blogger, blog, blogger-themes

Blogger allows in their WYSIWYG editor (What You See Is What You Get) to resize text in one of few options: (Smallest, Small, Normal, Large, Largest).

I've modified my template to change the `<Group description="Page Text" selector="body">` to be 22px. Essentially making any default text in the blog of size 22px.

The problem is that now when I choose to set fonts as Largest in the post editor, the final result makes of an almost identical size between the two text styles, the normal `Page Text` and the "Largest" headings.

How can I re-set the Largest font to be bigger than 22px?

PS.

When editing posts in HTML mode of the editor, the "Largest" tag is represented as:

`<span style="font-family: inherit; font-size: x-large;">TEXT GOES HERE</span>`

And also, if I replace `x-large` with something like `80px`, it will actually override that setting and show a correct 80px-sized text. How can I automate this and either replace `x-large` with `80px` in the whole blog, or re-set `x-large` to equal `80px`?